Diameter of $S_{n^2}$ with respect to two copies of $S_{n} \wr S_{n}$
Let $G=S_{n^2}$ the symmetric group on a grid of $n^2$ letters.
Now $G$ contains a maximal subgroup $H \cong S_n \wr S_n$ by the O'Nan-Scott theorem, and we can think of elements that look something like $(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n)\tau$ where $\sigma_i$ acts on the $i$th row of letters, permuting letters within the row, and $\tau$ permutes the rows themselves.
Similarly, there exists another isomorphic copy of this subgroup, call it $H'$ that acts as above but on columns. By maximality, $G=\langle H, H' \rangle$.
So then my question: what is the diameter of the Cayley graph $\Gamma (G,H\cup H')$?

A cool question! I can't help but think about it in terms of a puzzle game, seeking to move items on an $n\times n$ grid into desired positions,  alternating moves from $H$ and $H'$. Rubik style except that I don't think a mechanical device can support either $H$ or $H'$ :-). It's easy to see how to get any 2-cycle in $S_{n^2}$ with three moves, but ... at that point I realized this question is most likely beyond me :-)

Unless I made a mistake, when $n=2$ the answer is $3$. In that case both $H$ and $H'$ are Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_4$. They intersect in a subgroup of size $4$, so $HH'$ is a subset of size $16$, but $HH'H$ covers all three (right) cosets of $H$, and is thus all of $S_4$.

If you see a cool question (not straight out of several books), do bring it up in the Pearl Dive.

Next up $n=3$ :-)

Thanks for continuing to think about this Jyrki -- I was also thinking a little about generating the 2-cycles: if we could generate an arbitrary involution in a short length, say $c$ then the diameter will be bounded by $2c$ as $S_n$ is strongly real.
My naiive hope is that for large enough $n$, the answer is two - the size of the subgroups would at least allow that. I expect that'd be difficult to prove though

You could use GAP for small values of $n$, I guess.

I don't think the diameter can ever be $2$, just by looking at the potential size of $|HH'|$. It's way too small once $n>4$.

https://docs.gap-system.org/pkg/grape/htm/CHAP002.htm#SECT007

@SteveD Perhaps there's a mistake in my rough estimates but I had $\vert S_n \wr S_n\vert= (n!)^{n+1} \sim n^{n^2+n}$. And so $\vert H \vert \cdot \vert H' \vert \sim n^{O(2n^2)}$ which matches $\vert S_{n^2} \vert = (n^2)! \sim n^{2n^2}$?

What does Stirling's approximation give you?

My workings above used a cruder Stirling's approximation $n!\sim n^n$ but if we use the proper one I get
$ (\vert H \vert \cdot \vert H' \vert)^2 = ((n!)^{2n+2})^2 \sim
\frac{(2\pi)^{2n+2}}{e^{4n(n+1)}}n^{(2n+1)(2n+2)}.
$
This will grow larger than
$
\vert S_{n^2} \vert = (n^2)! \sim \frac{(2 \pi)^{1/2}}{e^{n^2}}\cdot n^{2n^2+1}
$
Plugging the formulae involving factorial into Wolfram Alpha also suggest that $\vert H \vert^4$ will dominate $\vert S_{n^2}\vert$.

But do you really get $|H|^4$ paths with two edges? The edges along a path in the Cayley graph need to alternate between $H$ and $H'$, because you can always combine two edges from the same subgroup.

Ah yes, of course you are both right. I slipped into thinking of single edges as an element from $HH'$ which is incorrect. So the above argument would suggest an optimistic bound of 4 then.

Added an incomplete construction to prove the diameter will always be 3 below. I am trying to solve for the incomplete part now but am stuck, any help is appreciated.

OK here is an answer, showing the diamater is $3$ for almost all $n$.
The diameter cannot be $2$, simply by size considerations of $|HH'|$, which has relative size in $S_{n^2}$ at most (by Stirling's approximation)
\begin{equation}
\frac{(n!)^{2n+2}}{(n^2)!}\sim \sqrt{2\pi}\Big(\frac{2\pi}{e^2}\Big)^n\Big(\frac{n^3}{e^n}\Big)^n \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
Now to show it has diameter $3$, we need to be able to transform any permutation in $S_{n^2}$ to the identity via an element of $H'HH'$. Write this arbitrary permutation as an $n\times n$ matrix, for example
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
4&3&9\\\color{red}{1}&2&7\\5&6&8
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Since $1$ is in the fourth position (left to right, top to bottom), this says that the permutation sends $4$ to $1$.
[Work the examples from bottom to top to see this matrix transformed to the identity.]
In order for an element of $H'$ to send a matrix to the identity, a necessary and sufficient condition is that in each column, all entries are equivalent $\pmod{n}$. Call such a matrix mod-constant. To get this to the identity, first sort the columns by this common modulus, then sort within each column. Example:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
6&4&8\\3&7&5\\9&1&2
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
4&8&6\\7&5&3\\1&2&9
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
In order to get an arbitrary matrix to be mod-constant via an element of $H$, it is necessary and suficient that each row of the matrix has no two elements of the same remainder $\pmod{n}$. Call such a matrix good. To get it into the mod-constant state, just sort each row by remainder. Example:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
4&6&8\\5&3&7\\1&2&9
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
6&4&8\\3&7&5\\9&1&2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Finally, in order to get an arbitrary matrix into a good configuration via an element of $H'$, it is necessary to permute each column such that no two elements of the same remainder end up in the same row. To show this is possible, we reduce every entry in our matrix $\pmod{n}$. Then we have an $n\times n$ grid, with $n$ 0's, $n$ 1's, etc.
Define for each $0\le i<n$ the set $A_i$ to be the column indices containing at least one $i$. Then the family $\{A_i\}$ satisifes the conditions of Hall's marriage theorem, and so there is a transversal; that is, a set of column indices $\{c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{n-1}\}$ that are mutually distinct and column $c_i$ contains $i$. Now permute each column to bring that $i$ to the top row. The first row is now good, and we are left with an $(n-1)\times n$ grid with $(n-1)$ 0's, $(n-1)$ 1's, etc. So we repeat this process, leaving the first row alone. Inductively we make this arbitrary matrix good, and our proof is complete. Example:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}{4}&3&9\\1&2&7\\5&\color{red}{6}&\color{red}{8}
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
4&6&8\\1&2&\color{blue}{7}\\\color{blue}{5}&\color{blue}{3}&9\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
4&6&8\\5&3&7\\1&2&9
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Edit The answer was incomplete with Step 3 before, but thanks to @Steve D's answer I have added it now

I will show that the diameter of this graph is $3$ for all $n$. To prove this, I will construct an algorithm which, given any two elements of group $a,b \in G$, can always find a path from $a$ to $b$ using elements from $H$ and $H'$.
Naming
Before strarting on the details of the algorithm, w.l.o.g. we can name the letters of $b$ to be $(1,2,\dots,n^2)$ so that the resultant matrix looks like
$b = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & \dots & n \\
n+1 & n+2 & \dots & 2n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(n-1)n+1 & (n-1)n+2 & \dots & n^2
\end{bmatrix}
$
(Note that this is not (necessarily) the identity element of $G$, whereas just a naming of symbols)
Now $a$ is a permutation on these $n^2$ numbers in this matrix, which is trying to reach back to $b$ using $3$ actions from $H$ and $H'$, and it will have $2$ intermediate matrices in this process. I'll name them as $a_1$ and $a_2$ here, so that the process looks like $a \rightarrow a_1 \rightarrow a_2 \rightarrow b$
Algorithm
Step 3
The last step ($3^{rd}$ step) of the algorithm will be an action from $H$, which permutes the $i^th$ row of $a_2$ using a permutation $\sigma_i$, and then the rows itself using a different permutation $\tau$. For our algorithm: $\tau$ is the identity permutation here.
To allow these row permutations $\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_n\}$ to convert $a_2$ into $b$, the only condition we require is that all numbers must be in their correct row in $a_2$, i.e., $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ in row $1$, $\{n+1, n+2, \dots, 2n\}$ in row $2$, and so on.
Step 2
The second last step ($2^{nd}$ step) will be an action from $H'$ which permutes the $i^th$ column of $a_1$ using a permutation $\sigma_i$, and then the rows itself using a different permutation $\tau$. Again, we keep $\tau$ as the identity permutation here.
To satisfy the condition for $a_2$, we must use these column permutations to bring every number to their correct row. For simplicty, lets color the numbers from the $i^{th}$ row in color $c_i$, i.e., $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ are of color $c_1$, $\{n+1, n+2, \dots, 2n\}$ are of color $c_2$, and so on.
Then the purpose of each column permutation $\sigma_i$ in this step, is to bring all numbers in the $i^{th}$ column of color $c_1$ to row $1$, of color $c_2$ to row $2$, and so on. This is only possible on the following condition: Each column in $a_1$ must contain one and only one number of each of the colors in set $\{c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n\}$
Step 1
The third last step ($1^{st}$ step) will again use an action from $H$ with $\tau$ as identity. This is the step which converts any arbitrary $a$ into $a_1$ with the above condition, for the algorithm to procede.
The construction of this step is present in this answer. The question is reframed there as follows:

The colors in the above question signify the same thing as the colors discussed in step $2$
Bags $[b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n]$ are initial rows of $a$
Bags $[b'_1, b'_2, \dots, b'_n]$ are the resulting columns in $a_1$

This gives an upper bound for the diameter as $3$, but to prove it as exactly $3$, we need to prove the lower bound as well.
Lower Bound
We use two particular elements $a,b \in G$ and show that there are no possible actions $h_1, h_2 \in H \cup H'$ which can satisfy $h_2 \cdot h_1 \cdot a = b$. This will show the diamter to be at least $3$
The elements we take are $b = e = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & \dots & n \\
n+1 & n+2 & \dots & 2n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(n-1)n+1 & (n-1)n+2 & \dots & n^2
\end{bmatrix}$ and $a = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & n+1 & \dots & n \\
2 & n+2 & \dots & 2n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(n-1)n+1 & (n-1)n+2 & \dots & n^2
\end{bmatrix}$
Missing a few steps here, we can also show that if there exists no possible $h_1, h_2$ for the above matrices in $n=2$, then we won't have any possible solutions in $n>2$ either.
So we just need to show that $a=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$ can not be converted to $b = e = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$ in less than $3$ steps, which I have verified manually as well as with the help of a computer.

This is a nice answer. Here is how I have been thinking about it, which I think agrees with what you wrote, but recasts it a bit. Diameter 2 is too small from size considerations (discussed in comments above). In order for an element of $H'$ to convert an $n\times n$ matrix to the identity permutation, it is necessary and sufficient that each column is constant $\pmod{n}$. In order for a matrix to be transformed (via $H$) to this special type of matrix, it is necessary and sufficient that each row contains a full set of representatives $\pmod{n}$...

... And to get an arbitrary matrix into this special form via $H'$, one needs to permute each column so that for $0\le i<n$, no row has $i\pmod{n}$ more than once. This seems intuitively obvious, but I don't have a full proof at the moment.

Yeah this seems like a short summary of my answer. The main problem is the arbitrary matrix to the special one. I remember doing a very similar problem in a coding contest some years ago, but I just can't remember what contest was that now

It feels very similar to a contest math problem. I'm gonna search and see if I can find a solution :).

Ok I believe I have figured it out, using Hall's marriage theorem and induction. The idea is to define for each $0\le i<n$, the set $A_i$ of column indices containing a value $\equiv i\pmod{n}$. The family ${A_i}$ satisfies the conditions of the marriage theorem, so there's a transversal, meaning for each $i$ we pick a column index $c_i$ containing $i$, such that the $c_i$ are distinct. Now permute each column to "bubble up" all these $i$ to the first row. Now do the same for the second row, etc.

I checked your answer now, very nice proof. I was trying to use network flow in my linked question ( which uses the graph version of hall's marriage) but I didn't knew about the combinatorial one.

A minor addendum to Steve D's answer: The diameter is always $3$, for all $n \geq 2$. To see this, consider matrices $X$ and $Y$ with $X_{11} = Y_{11} = 1$, $X_{12} = Y_{21} = 2$ and $X_{21} = Y_{12} = 3$. I claim that there is no length $2$ path $X \leadsto Z \leadsto Y$.
First, suppose that we use $H$ to go from $X$ to $Z$, and $H'$ to go from $Z$ to $Y$. Since we use $H$ to go between $X$ and $Z$, the rows of $Z$ (as sets) are the same as the rows of $X$ (as sets), so $1$ and $2$ are in the same row of $Z$. But, since we use $H'$ to go between $Z$ and $Y$, we see that $1$ and $2$ are in the same column of $Z$; a contradiction.
If we instead use $H'$ to go from $X$ to $Z$, and $H$ to go from $Z$ to $Y$, then we get the same contradiction by looking at the positions of $1$ and $3$.
